# Is there a way to request both camera permission and photo library permission at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, uiimagepickercontroller, access-control

I am creating an application that gives users the option to upload a profile picture. I am using [Fusuma](https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma) as a third party substitute for `UIImagePickerController`. It has a bug that is requiring me to ask for camera and photo library permission **before** presenting the image picking view controller (`FusumaViewController`). I am able to request photo library permission via `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in }`, but when the image picking view controller is presented, it then asks for camera access. I'm wanting to request access to **both** the camera and the photo library **at the same time**, is this possible?

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Many thanks for the timely response @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

Per rmaddy's qualified comment, you cannot request both at the same time. Still, I figured I would share how I present the two requests **back-to-back**, which is about as good as we can get.

```swift
import UIKit
import Photos

class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    @IBAction func requestAccessButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in

            //Use PHAuthorizationStatus as you need here

            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in 

                //Use the boolean "response", which tells us whether the user granted photo access here

            }
        }
    }
}
```